# Перетаскивание виджетов PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, drag-n-drop, mousemove, eventfilter

Начал изучать *PyQt5* и столкнулся с таким вопросом.
При создании десктопного приложения возникла необходимость перетаскивать виджеты в любое место родительского блока. К примеру имеется несколько виджетов `QLineEdit`, `QLabel`, `QComboBox`, расположены в одном родительском блоке.

Как можно реализовать такой функционал по типу `Drag & Drop` только перетаскивать нужно не данные элементов, а сами виджеты путем манипуляции мышкой.

Например имеется такой экран с элементами

[image: пример 1]

Далее простыми перетаскиваниями мышью получить такой результат

[image: пример 2]

Возможна ли такая реализация используя данную библиотеку?

Пример кода

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(739, 543)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 431, 491))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 70, 104, 26))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Form", "Именование"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "кг"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "гр"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Заголовок"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: покажите ваш код, который показывает окно изображенное на первом изображении.

Comment: добавил в описание вопроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант. Жмем **ПКМ** и перетаскиваем.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(739, 543)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 431, 491))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 70, 104, 26))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Form", "Именование"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "кг"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "гр"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Заголовок"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.movingButton = None
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.button.setFixedSize(100,100)
        self.button.move(100, 350)
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.comboBox.installEventFilter(self)
        self.lineEdit.installEventFilter(self)
        self.lineEdit_2.installEventFilter(self)
        
    def eventFilter(self, source, event):        
        if source in (self.button, self.comboBox, self.lineEdit, self.lineEdit_2):
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and \
                event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                self.movingButton = source
                self.startPos = event.pos()
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.movingButton:                
                self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and self.movingButton:
                self.movingButton.move(source.pos() + event.pos() - self.startPos)
                self.movingButton = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)                
      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(431, 491)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @NickDeniel я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Да. Ваш ответ вполне понятен. Только когда я реализовал его в своем коде? который имеет уже другую структуру, такой способ не работает.

Comment: @NickDeniel вы задали вопрос, привели пример. Я привел вам вариант решения, согласно вашего кода. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос, приведите минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему, напишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.